# How to plot a triangle heatmap using ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a big dataframe, the head of which is like this.

```
structure(list(SFE_1 = c("MAP2K4", "STK11", "AKT1", "AKT1", "NF1", 
"EGFR", "KDM5A", "AXIN1", "AMP.JAK2", "AMP.LYN", "CNOT3", "AMP.NSD3"
), SFE_2 = c("KDM5A", "AXIN1", "AMP.JAK2", "AMP.LYN", "CNOT3", 
"AMP.NSD3", "MAP2K4", "STK11", "AKT1", "AKT1", "NF1", "EGFR"), 
    overlap = c(0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("MAP2K4 - KDM5A", 
"STK11 - AXIN1", "AKT1 - AMP.JAK2", "AKT1 - AMP.LYN", "NF1 - CNOT3", 
"EGFR - AMP.NSD3", "MAP2K4 - KDM5A1", "STK11 - AXIN11", "AKT1 - AMP.JAK21", 
"AKT1 - AMP.LYN1", "NF1 - CNOT31", "EGFR - AMP.NSD31"))
```

I want to plot a triangle heatmap using ggplot2 and I tried the code:

```
ggplot(df_triheatmap, aes(SFE_1, SFE_2, fill = overlap)) +
  geom_raster() +
  scale_fill_distiller(palette = "Spectral") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank())
```

The output was
[image]

It looks like mirror symmetry. I want to know how to modify the input dataframe to keep only the upper or lower triangle heatmap. Thank you.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be a bit too "basic" (I guess there are shorter & smarter solutions), but it results in your wanted output:

I would create dummy data for the lower triangle:

```
dummy_x <- c()
dummy_y <- c()
for (i in 1:length(unique(df_triheatmap$SFE_1))) {
  dummy_x <- c(dummy_x, rep(i, i))
  dummy_y <- c(dummy_y, 1:i)
}
```

And just add white tiles on top:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_raster(data = df_triheatmap, aes(SFE_1, SFE_2, fill = overlap)) +
  scale_fill_distiller(palette = "Spectral") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank()) +
  geom_raster(aes(x=dummy_x, y=dummy_y), fill = "white")
```

And this is the output:

[image]

(However, I did not change the data, but rather the plot.)

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for such a solution?

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 <- df %>%
    rownames_to_column("combination") %>% 
    arrange(combination) %>% 
    filter(row_number() %% 2 != 1) ## Delete even-rows

ggplot(df1, aes(x=SFE_1, y=SFE_2, fill=overlap)) +
    geom_tile(color="white")+
    scale_fill_distiller(palette = "Spectral") +
    theme_bw()+
    theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=45, vjust=1, size=10, hjust=1))+
    coord_fixed()+
    labs(x="",y="")
```

[image]

Comment: Hi. I have edited my question and added the output I want.